# How to pass a function from modal to parent component with differences

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I have looked at some examples hence the title has 'with differences' added.

In the examples, modal loads in to a custom tag of the parent component: i.e.

```html
  template: `
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <template ngbModalContainer></template>
    <ngbd-modal-component (notifyParent)="getNotification($event)"></ngbd-modal-component>
  </div>
  `
```

But I do not have a custom tag. Modal perfectly loads into body where I want it to be.

Here is the home.component.html

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-expand-md justify-content-between fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-brand mr-auto">
                <a class="navbar-brand" title="appChoser" href="appChooser" target="_self" >
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu"></span>
                </a>

            <a class="navbar-brand logo" title="" routerLink="/dashboard" rel="home"></a>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"  [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse" >
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ellipsis"></span>
        </button>


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed" id="bs-navbar-collapse">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                 <li class="navbar-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" ui-sref="simListView" ui-sref-active="active" title="SIM list"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-icons2"></span><span class="d-md-none d-lg-inline">Sim List</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbar-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" ui-sref="reportsView" title="Reports"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chart-bars"></span><span class="d-md-none d-lg-inline">Reports</span></a>
                </li>

                    <li class="navbar-item" >
                        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/hierarchy-mgmt" title="Show Managed Accounts" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-group-work"></span><span class="d-md-none d-lg-inline">Managed Accounts</span></a>
                    </li>

            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="navbar-item" id="about_top_menu_button">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)" target="_self" (click)="open();" title="About Estate Management"><span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-ark-info-circle"></span><span class="d-md-none d-lg-inline">About</span></a>
                </li>

                <li class="navbar-item" >
                    <a class="nav-link"   title="Frequently Asked Questions and much more"><span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-circle"></span><span class="d-md-none d-lg-inline">Help</span></a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class="d-sm-none" id="loggedinas">Welcome,<br/>User</div>
                </li>
                <li ngbDropdown class="dropdown" >
                    <a  id="userDropdown" href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"  ngbDropdownToggle>
                        <span class="glyphicon "></span>
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
                        <div class="identity-cell"  id="notify_identity" >Identity: {{user}}</div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/assume-id" title="Assume another user&#39;s identity">Assume Identity</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/my-profile" title="My user account details">My Profile</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="logout();" title="Log out from Estate Management">Logout</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- navbar collapse -->
</nav>
```

So I am not sure what I need to do. I emit  I think a function from modal component like this.

```html
import {Component,Output, EventEmitter, Input} from '@angular/core';

import {NgbModal, NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-content',
  template: `
    <div (processYes)="processYes();" class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>
      <ng-template #tipContent>{{tip}}</ng-template>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)"><span [ngbTooltip]="tipContent" placement="right"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-ark-info-circle">Info</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close()">No</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="yes()">Yes</button>
    </div>
  `
})
export class NgbdModalContent {
  @Input() name;
  @Input() tip;
  @Output() processYes: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  
   yes(){
        console.log('Notify clicked...');
        this.processYes.emit();
        this.activeModal.close('Yes click');
    }
 

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {
    
    
  }
}
```

And my home component -which is only Navigation at the moment- should receive the  function from 'Yes' button and do something with it, mainly run a new function within itself. Here is the code:

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbdModalContent } from './modal.component';
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl:'src/home.content.html' 
})


export class HomeComponent {
  
  processYes(){
    console.log('run a new function of this component here');
  }
  
 constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
    modalRef.componentInstance.tip = 'Well this is a tooltip';
  
    }

  
}
```

What is the shortest way? Why there is emit and output modules needed if home component can actually reference to modal component anyway in the example of opening it or putting in data?

here is also plunker version. https://plnkr.co/edit/ZcD8NnHe0RqlwTDOA5Pz?p=preview

Comment: did you resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call emitResponse out of open function

```
open() {
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
  modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World Welcome';
  modalRef.componentInstance.emitData.subscribe(($e) => {
    this.recive($e);
  })
}

recive(event) {
  console.log('event', event);
}
```

Try like this :

I just referred your plunker code do like below :

model.compoent.ts

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

import {NgbModal, NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-content',
  template: `
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="add()">Emit</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
  `
})
export class NgbdModalContent {
  @Input() name;
  @Output() emitData = new EventEmitter();
  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}

  add() {
    this.emitData.next('Hello world');
  }
}
```

And home.component.ts

```
open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
    modalRef.componentInstance.emitData.subscribe(($e) => {
      console.log('$e', $e);
    })
  }
```

Comment: this works but how can I move this out of open function? actually I can see there is no need for that because this only runs after the click. SO I think I can  just run the function here.

Answer (score 1):

> Why there is emit and output modules needed if home component can actually reference to modal component anyway in the example of opening it or putting in data?

`@Input` and `@Output` are both one-way bindings.

> What is the shortest way?

You're already on the right track here by setting up your `@Output` in the `ModalComponent` that is assigned to an `EventEmitter`. You're also on the right track in passing the emitted event through your `HomeComponent` template, but you'll need to make sure the variable and function names match your code, like this:

```
(processYes)="processYes()"
```

The left-side of the assignment is your `@Output` variable, the right-side of the assignment is the function from your `HomeComponent`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But as I mentioned I do not have template in home. It has its own html which is navigation but I did not put a custom tag for modal to be attached to. Though let me try with that.

Comment: Okay, if you don't have a parent-child relationship between `Home` and `Modal`, you'll need to use a shared service for the components to communicate.

Comment: I added `<ngbd-modal-content #activeModal (emitData)="processYes()"></ngbd-modal-content>` to my home.component.html but I am getting error. (No provider for NgbActiveModal!). I find this more complicated. I changed the code if you don't mind looking.

Comment: Can you add the code for your `Home` html -
 `templateUrl:'src/home.content.html'`?

Comment: It's interesting that you hadn't been getting this error before. To me, that says you'll need to add `NgbActiveModal` to a `providers` array. This can be in your `HomeComponent` if you only plan to use `NgbActiveModal` in this component, otherwise add it to your main `module` and it will be available throughout your app.

Comment: `NgbActiveModal` is imported in home component. I didn't need it in app component before but I added the html into the original question. At the moment I have no more `ngbd-model-content` selector tag  I deleted since the error. Subscribe to emitted function worked as @Chandru suggested but is there a preferred version for passing it through template?

Comment: Passing through the template would only apply if `Home` were the parent of `Modal`. Otherwise you'll need to use a shared service as @Chandru suggested. Is it working how you're expecting now?

Comment: Yes at the moment I can run a home.component function from within `modalRef.componentInstance.emitData.subscribe(($e) => {}` 
Thanks, I will read more to understand better :)

Answer (score 0):

you can just do like below code, if you want to run some method in the component used to create the modal.

```
modalRef.content.yourMethod();
```